# How to repetitively divide each column in dataframe A by median of same column in dataframe B?

Tags: r, function, dplyr, apply

I have a dataframe "tmp" where each column contains list of readings for a particular sample. I have another dataframe "tmpb" containing the background noise readings. I want to divide each entry in each column from "tmp" by the median of the corresponding column from "tmpb" dataframe. I tried using sapply and transmute (dplyr) but finding it difficult to understand their syntax and use it for my problem (I am a R novice).

I managed to achieve what I want with a for loop but could someone show me to do this in a more straightforward way?

```
head (tmp)

   Time C2F9RA23   C2F9RD   C2F9RZ C2F9DA23   C2F9DD   C2F9DZ
5     5 365.9755 209.9572 559.2779 233.4608 135.1393 198.7386
6     6 351.4190 241.1814 593.3041 224.5569 135.7866 229.8217
7     7 343.7087 224.6147 575.8846 238.8623 139.4048 193.8843
8     8 351.1890 207.5736 589.4181 242.7238 139.4259 213.2959
```

```
head(tmpb)

Time C2F9RA23   C2F9RD   C2F9RZ C2F9DA23   C2F9DD   C2F9DZ
5     5 365.9755 209.9572 559.2779 233.4608 135.1393 198.7386
6     6 351.4190 241.1814 593.3041 224.5569 135.7866 229.8217
7     7 343.7087 224.6147 575.8846 238.8623 139.4048 193.8843
8     8 351.1890 207.5736 589.4181 242.7238 139.4259 213.2959
```

What I tried with for loop-

```
output<-data.frame(tmp$Time)
for (i in 2:ncol(tmp)) {
output<- data.frame(output,tmp[,i]/median(tmpb[,i],na.rm=T)) 
}
 colnames(cakin_norm2)<-colnames(tmp)

head(output)

Time C2F9RA23    C2F9RD   C2F9RZ  C2F9DA23    C2F9DD   C2F9DZ
1    5 1.109141 0.9831341 1.281213 0.9182793 0.9938967 1.038065
2    6 1.065026 1.1293430 1.359162 0.8832571 0.9986575 1.200421
3    7 1.041658 1.0517686 1.319256 0.9395253 1.0252683 1.012710
4    8 1.064328 0.9719731 1.350260 0.9547136 1.0254230 1.114102
```

Could anyone show me how to do this with less code using apply or mutate or some other command? Would help me a lot in the future!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option to get the `colMedians` (from `matrixStats`) and divide the columns in 'tmp' by the same replicated medians from 'tmpb'

```
library(matrixStats)
tmp[-1] <- tmp[-1]/colMedians(as.matrix(tmpb[names(tmp)[-1]]))[col(tmpb[-1])]
tmp
#  Time  C2F9RA23    C2F9RD    C2F9RZ  C2F9DA23    C2F9DD    C2F9DZ
#5    5 1.0417630 0.9662714 0.9598843 0.9885640 0.9821477 0.9646697
#6    6 1.0003274 1.1099724 1.0182832 0.9508614 0.9868521 1.1155459
#7    7 0.9783797 1.0337286 0.9883863 1.0114360 1.0131479 0.9411071
#8    8 0.9996726 0.9553015 1.0116137 1.0277871 1.0133013 1.0353303
```

---

Or in `base R` we can also do

```
tmp[-1] <- tmp[-1]/vapply(tmpb[-1], median, numeric(1))[col(tmp[-1])]
```

Or another option is `Map`

```
tmp[-1] <- Map(`/`, tmp[-1], lapply(tmpb[-1], median))
```

Or another option is

```
tmp[-1] <-  t(t(tmp[-1])/colMedians(as.matrix(tmpb[-1])))
```

---

In `tidyverse`, we can use `map2`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map2_df(tmp[-1], tmpb[-1], ~ .x/median(.y)) %>%
       bind_cols(tmp[1], .)
```

NOTE: All the methods give the correct output i.e. divide each column of the 'tmp' by the **corresponding** column median of the second dataset

#### data

```
tmp <- structure(list(Time = 5:8, C2F9RA23 = c(365.9755, 351.419, 343.7087, 
351.189), C2F9RD = c(209.9572, 241.1814, 224.6147, 207.5736), 
    C2F9RZ = c(559.2779, 593.3041, 575.8846, 589.4181), C2F9DA23 = c(233.4608, 
    224.5569, 238.8623, 242.7238), C2F9DD = c(135.1393, 135.7866, 
    139.4048, 139.4259), C2F9DZ = c(198.7386, 229.8217, 193.8843, 
    213.2959)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("5", "6", 
"7", "8"))

tmpb <- structure(list(Time = 5:8, C2F9RA23 = c(365.9755, 351.419, 343.7087, 
351.189), C2F9RD = c(209.9572, 241.1814, 224.6147, 207.5736), 
    C2F9RZ = c(559.2779, 593.3041, 575.8846, 589.4181), C2F9DA23 = c(233.4608, 
    224.5569, 238.8623, 242.7238), C2F9DD = c(135.1393, 135.7866, 
    139.4048, 139.4259), C2F9DZ = c(198.7386, 229.8217, 193.8843, 
    213.2959)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("5", "6", 
"7", "8"))
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain this part- [col(tmpb[-1])] in your matrixstats solution?

Comment: @Abgan. I believe you don't want to divide the first column, so removed it

Comment: Lots of options! I like the "apply" solutions best though. Thank you @akrun.

Comment: @Abgan Also, when you divide a data.frame by a vector, make sure to replicate it, otherwise gets false results

Comment: @Abgan Note that the other solution gives wrong values.  Please check

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Your first solution using matrixstats also gives wrong values somehow. Other suggested solutions all work. Accepting your answer as I learnt more ways to solve it.

Comment: @Abgan I tried all the methods and all of them are giving same output though. based on the data showed in my post

Comment: Could you check again? The matrixstats solution gives the 1st column right but the other columns are wrong.

Comment: @Abgan I checked again with the `Map`, it is giving same output

Comment: @Abgan `all.equal(tmp[-1]/colMedians(as.matrix(tmpb[names(tmp)[-1]]))[col(tmpb[-1])], data.frame(Map(`/`, tmp[-1], lapply(tmpb[-1], median))
+), check.attributes = FALSE)
[1] TRUE`

Comment: Sorry, I was trying out your solutions on my entire dataframe (what I had posted was just the first 4 rows. My dataframe has some missing values near the end, maybe thats why the values are wrong? Other solutions work on the entire dataframe though. I tried na.rm=T in colMedians, still wrong.
This is the output in first 2 rows-
`1.109141 0.8258316 3.720476 1.785782 0.4095589 0.7817053
6  1.065026 0.9486469 3.946828 1.717674 0.4115207 0.9039655`

Comment: @Abgan Okay, that is the issue, then you need `na.rm = TRUE` in `colMedians`

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility could be:

```
sweep(df[-1], 2, sapply(df2[-1], median), "/")

   C2F9RA23    C2F9RD    C2F9RZ  C2F9DA23    C2F9DD    C2F9DZ
5 1.0417630 0.9662714 0.9598843 0.9885640 0.9821477 0.9646697
6 1.0003274 1.1099724 1.0182832 0.9508614 0.9868521 1.1155459
7 0.9783797 1.0337286 0.9883863 1.0114360 1.0131479 0.9411071
8 0.9996726 0.9553015 1.0116137 1.0277871 1.0133013 1.0353303
```

Comment: Should you need to retain *Time* (if different from `row.names`), wrap in `cbind`: `cbind(Time=df1$Time, df1[-1] / sapply(df2[-1], median))`

Comment: @akrun was right. The previous solution `tmp[-1]/sapply(tmpb[-1], median)` gave wrong values. The present "sweep" solution works.